# MVC RadioButtonFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have something along the following:

```
     <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TotalCol, "Yes")  @Html.Label("Yes")&nbsp;&nbsp; 
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TotalCol, "No") @Html.Label("No")
```

Note that TotalCol is a string.

```
    public string TotalCol { get; set; }
```

I use the following to get the value:

```
    var TotalCo = $('#TotalCol').val();
    alert(TotalCo);
```

the alert show Yes.

If I do an alert on submit of the form without selecting either the Yes or No, I still
get Yes. Why is that. Why doesn't it just return blank.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you call that particular view, is TotalCol empty or does it actually have any value?

Comment: It is empty. I use the following to get the value  var TotalCo = $('#TotalCol').val();

Comment: You need $('input[name=TotalCol]:checked').val()

Comment: You can check the rendered markup for both yes and no. One of them will id as TotalCol while the other one will have different id. So that yes is returned

Comment: So what do you say @NatePet, did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at you code I see that your RadioButtons are actually "grouped" together as #TotalCol and therefore the jquery can only grap the first element and display for you the val from that particular element of the group.  For instance if you were to reverse this you would get the opposite result (alert would return "No" like this):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TotalCol, "No") @Html.Label("No")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TotalCol, "Yes")  @Html.Label("Yes")&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I hope this is making any sense  :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have two radio buttons with the same name (or ID) you need to find out which one was selected. You can do that by using the selector `:checked`.

Example:

```
 $('#TotalCol:checked').val();
```

or

```
 $('input[name=TotalCol]:checked').val();
```